# How to list all present optical drivers?

Tags: linux, shell, perl, drivers, udev

How can I list all the installed optical drivers with *udev* or any other core-based tool (perl is also very good) ?

P.S.: I know about the `wodim --devices` command, but it's an undesirable dependence.

Answer (score 1):

If you like Perl, then this example code [found](http://search.cpan.org/~rocky/Device-Cdio-v0.3.0/lib/perlmmc.pm) in CPAN could do the trick. It also have low dependencies.
The library you need is [Device-Cdio](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/R/RO/ROCKY/Device-Cdio-v0.3.0.tar.gz).

```
use strict;

BEGIN {
    chdir 'example' if -d 'example';
    use lib '../lib';
    eval "use blib";  # if we fail keep going - maybe we have installed Cdio
}

use Device::Cdio;
use Device::Cdio::Device;
use Device::Cdio::Track;
use vars qw($0 $program $pause %opts);

sub print_drive_class($$$) {
    my ($msg, $bitmask, $any) = @_;
    my @cd_drives = Device::Cdio::get_devices_with_cap($bitmask, $any);
    print "$msg...\n";
    foreach my $drive (@cd_drives) {
    print "Drive $drive\n";
    }
    print "-----\n";
}
my @cd_drives = Device::Cdio::get_devices($perlcdio::DRIVER_DEVICE);
foreach my $drive (@cd_drives) {
    print "Drive $drive\n";
}
print "-----\n";
print_drive_class("All CD-ROM drives (again)", $perlcdio::FS_MATCH_ALL, 0);
```

Comment: `dmesg  | awk '/CD-ROM/ && /Attached/{print "/dev/"$NF}'`

Comment: @RahulPatil is this supposed to work ? Because it doesn't in my system.